# Build src knox 1.4.0 with hadoop 2.7.4 failed

Tags: apache-knox

I tried to build the project Apache Knox 1.4.0 with hadoop 2.7.4
I did the build on a Ubuntu server :
- Ubtuntu 18.04
- Openjdk version "11.0.7"
- Apache Maven 3.6.0
- Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.5

I have downloaded the src archive on http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/knox/1.4.0/knox-1.4.0-src.zip
I get the following issue, and I'm looking for a solution :

```
/var/compil/knox/knox-1.4.0# mvn -Panalyze -Prelease clean install -DskipTests

[WARNING]
Dependency convergence error for org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-kerberos-codec:2.0.0-M15 paths to dependency are:
+-org.apache.knox:gateway-server:1.4.0
  +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:2.7.4
    +-org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-kerberos-codec:2.0.0-M15

[WARNING]
Dependency convergence error for org.apache.directory.api:api-asn1-api:1.0.0-M20 paths to dependency are:
+-org.apache.knox:gateway-server:1.4.0
  +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:2.7.4
    +-org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-kerberos-codec:2.0.0-M15
      +-org.apache.directory.api:api-asn1-api:1.0.0-M20

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  04:30 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-14T11:20:57+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "analyze" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (enforce-dependencies) on project gateway-server: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: I don't get this error when I try this build without change the value of hadoop.version in the file pom.xml (keep the original value 3.2.1). The previous try has been done with hadoop.version = 2.7.4

Comment: I suspect a compatibility issue between Apache knox 1.4.0 and Hadoop 2.7.4